# Matlab figure as png

Tags: matlab, plot, png, matlab-figure

I am saving a matlab figure as png. I want to set the print size tight to the screen size, so I used:

```
set(gca(),'LooseInset',get(gca(),'TightInset')); %set print size tight to the screen size
```

However my image is not being saved tight to the screen size nor at the centre of the screen...

Here is my code with everything I already tried:

```
function []=FilledCircle1(x0,y0,Radius,N,col1)

if(N<=1)
    error('N must be greater than 1');
end

hold on
axis equal
% axis off
hold on 

t=(0:N)*2*pi/N; %t=-pi:0.01:pi
x=Radius*cos(t)+x0;
y=Radius*sin(t)+y0;


c1=fill(x,y,col1);

set (c1, 'edgecolor','k')

set(gcf,'PaperUnits','inches','PaperSize',[0.8666,0.8666],'PaperPosition',[0 0 0.8666 0.8666])%setting size (130/150, 130/150, 150pixels per inch being the default size of img), paper position is imporrtant as otherwise i will have extra border

% % set(gcf,'Position', [0 0 4.4466 3.5733], 'units','inches')
% % iptsetpref('ImshowBorder','tight');

set(gca(),'LooseInset',get(gca(),'TightInset')); %set print size tight to the screen size

% set(gcf, 'Position', get(0,'screensize'));

set(gcf,'color','none'); %set backgroound color to transparent 
fig = gcf;
fig.InvertHardcopy = 'off'; %saves the fig with the set background color
```

I would like my png file to look like this:

[image]

However it's looking like this:

[image]

Can someone help me understand what am I doing wrong?
Thank you!

Comment: It's not at all clear how the first image relates to the second. Regardless, insets apply to the *axes*, not what's plotted in it. If you want the plotted object to be centered and zoomed then you have to change the axes limits before you save it.

Comment: The first image is just to show that I want the filled circle I ploted to be centered and filling the all screen. @excaza

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is because the labels of the x and y ticks are displacing your graph.

[image]

Rather than messing with `TightInset`, I would just set the `Position` property of the `axes` to make the inside of the axes take up the entire figure

```
hfig = figure();
hax = axes();

t = (0:N)*2*pi/N; %t=-pi:0.01:pi
x = Radius*cos(t)+x0;
y = Radius*sin(t)+y0;

c1 = fill(x,y,col1);

set(c1, 'edgecolor','k')

set(hfig, 'PaperUnits', 'inches', ...
          'PaperSize', [0.8666,0.8666], ...
          'PaperPosition', [0 0 0.8666 0.8666], ...
          'InvertHardCopy', 'off')

axis(hax, 'equal')
axis(hax, 'off')

set(hax, 'Position', [0 0 1 1]); 
set(hfig, 'Color', 'none');

print(hfig, '-dpng', 'output.png')
```

[image]

You should also consider using [`export_fig`](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-export-fig) as it more faithfully reproduces the graphics shown on the screen.

Comment: export_fig saved my mental health multiple times, I also strongly advise its use.

Comment: Thank you @Suever!